# Extract values from array in python

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, key

I'm having some trouble accessing a value that is inside an array that contains a dictionary and another array.

It looks like this:

```
[{'name': 'Alex',
  'number_of_toys': [{'classification': 3, 'count': 383},
   {'classification': 1, 'count': 29},
   {'classification': 0, 'count': 61}],
  'total_toys': 473},
 {'name': 'John',
  'number_of_toys': [{'classification': 3, 'count': 8461},
   {'classification': 0, 'count': 3825},
   {'classification': 1, 'count': 1319}],
  'total_toys': 13605}]
```

I want to access the 'count' number for each 'classification'. For example, for 'name' Alex, if 'classification' is 3, then the code returns the 'count' of 383, and so on for the other classifications and names.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your question asks, but if it's just a mapping exercise this will get you on the right track.

```
def get_toys(personDict):
    person_toys = personDict.get('number_of_toys')
    return [ (toys.get('classification'), toys.get('count')) for toys in person_toys]

def get_person_toys(database):
    return [(personDict.get('name'), get_toys(personDict)) for personDict in database]
```

This result is:

`[('Alex', [(3, 383), (1, 29), (0, 61)]), ('John', [(3, 8461), (0, 3825), (1, 1319)])]`

Answer (score 0):

This isn't as elegant as the previous answer because it doesn't iterate over the values, but if you want to select specific elements, this is one way to do that:

```
data = [{'name': 'Alex',
  'number_of_toys': [{'classification': 3, 'count': 383},
   {'classification': 1, 'count': 29},
   {'classification': 0, 'count': 61}],
  'total_toys': 473},
 {'name': 'John',
  'number_of_toys': [{'classification': 3, 'count': 8461},
   {'classification': 0, 'count': 3825},
   {'classification': 1, 'count': 1319}],
  'total_toys': 13605}]    

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df.loc[0]['name'])
print(df.loc[0][1][0]['classification'])
print(df.loc[0][1][0]['count'])
```

which gives:

```
Alex
3
383
```